# Animate Collection View Bounds Change with Custom Layout Animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview

I have a collection view and I want it to have 2 states: collapsed and expanded.

Here are the two states:

[image: collapsed]
[image: expanded]

The collection view has a red background, the cells have a purple background, and the containing view of the collection view has a gray background.

I am using a custom subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout that handles paging, scaling, and opacity of the cells. The layout is supposed to assure that one of the cells is always centered.

---

### What I'm trying to achieve

A smooth animation between the two states where the cells simply grow/shrink with the collection view.

### What I'm experiencing

Since the width of the cell changes between the two states, I'm seeing not only the default fade animation between the cells, but also the cell that was centered in one state is no longer centered.

[image: current animation]

### What I tried

I tried following the [UPCarouselLayout](https://github.com/ink-spot/UPCarouselFlowLayout) for the initial layout. I tried following [this objc.io post](https://github.com/objcio/issue-12-CollectionViewAnimations) for animation ideas and specifically the section on device rotations. I wasn't able to use their approach because the frame returned by `layoutAttributesForElement(at indexPath: IndexPath)` was incorrect.

### The layout code

```
protocol TrayCarouselFlowLayoutDelegate: class {
    func sizeForItemInCarousel(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, _ layout: TrayCarouselFlowLayout) -> CGSize
}

class TrayCarouselFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    fileprivate var collectionViewSize: CGSize = .zero

    fileprivate var peekItemScale: CGFloat = 0.95
    fileprivate var peekItemAlpha: CGFloat = 0.65
    fileprivate var peekItemShift: CGFloat = 0.0

    var spacing = 16

    weak var delegate: TrayCarouselFlowLayoutDelegate!

    fileprivate var indexPathsToAnimate: [IndexPath] = []

    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()
        guard let size = collectionView?.bounds.size, collectionViewSize != size else { return }

        setUpCollectionView()
        updateLayout()
        collectionViewSize = size
    }

    fileprivate func setUpCollectionView() {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
        if collectionView.decelerationRate != UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast {
            collectionView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
        }
    }

    fileprivate func updateLayout() {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }

        itemSize = delegate.sizeForItemInCarousel(collectionView, self)

        let yInset = (collectionView.bounds.height - itemSize.height) / 2
        let xInset = (collectionView.bounds.width - itemSize.width) / 2
        sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: yInset, left: xInset, bottom: yInset, right: xInset)

        let side = itemSize.width
        let scaledItemOffset = (side - side * peekItemScale) / 2

        minimumLineSpacing = spacing - scaledItemOffset
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        let oldBounds = collectionView?.bounds ?? .zero

        if oldBounds != newBounds {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let superAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect),
            let attributes = NSArray(array: superAttributes, copyItems: true) as? [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
            else { return nil }
        return attributes.map { self.transformLayoutAttributes($0) }
    }

    fileprivate func transformLayoutAttributes(_ attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return attributes }

        let collectionCenter = collectionView.frame.size.width / 2
        let offset = collectionView.contentOffset.x
        let normalizedCenter = attributes.center.x - offset

        let maxDistance = itemSize.width + minimumLineSpacing
        let distance = min(abs(collectionCenter - normalizedCenter), maxDistance)
        let ratio = (maxDistance - distance) / maxDistance

        let alpha = ratio * (1 - peekItemAlpha) + peekItemAlpha
        let scale = ratio * (1 - peekItemScale) + peekItemScale
        let shift = (1 - ratio) * peekItemShift

        attributes.alpha = alpha
        attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, scale, scale, 1)
        attributes.zIndex = Int(alpha * 10)

        attributes.center.y += shift

        return attributes
    }

    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint,
                                      withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView, !collectionView.isPagingEnabled,
            let layoutAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForElements(in: collectionView.bounds)
            else { return super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset) }

        let midSide: CGFloat = collectionViewSize.width / 2
        let proposedContentOffsetCenterOrigin = proposedContentOffset.x + midSide

        let closest = layoutAttributes
            .sorted { abs($0.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterOrigin) < abs($1.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterOrigin) }
            .first ?? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes()
        let targetContentOffset = CGPoint(x: floor(closest.center.x - midSide), y: proposedContentOffset.y)

        return targetContentOffset
    }
}
```

### What I need help with

My goal is to simply grow the collection view and the cells along with it. Since I'm changing the section insets and the size of the cell in my code, the most challenging part is keeping the cell centered during the growth/shrinking. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** If I don't change the width of the cell when expanding/collapsing, this behaves ALMOST how I want it. There is still a fade animation but that would be acceptable if it was the only part off the mark. For some reason, redefining the width while the layout cells are growing is what is causing the issue seen in the GIF.

Here is a GIF where the width is static:

[image: no size change]

Comment: Running into the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?